# Talend - Error handling without using subjobs

Tags: talend

Please see the image.
[image: talend error handling issue]

So here is a flow, wherein the first component executes a database query to find QAR_ID (single row), if it is found then all well. I am trying to put error handling into this. When no rows are found, it directs to tJava_11 which raises an java exception and that gets logged by another tJava component.

The problem I am facing is when it goes to error handling flow, it logs the error and just goes to the post-job section. However, I want Talend to take the OnSubJobOk route so that it continues with other steps instead of directly jumping to post-job section.

I know this is possible using subjobs but I don't want to keep creating 'n' number of subjobs.

Is there any way this can be done in the same job?

Comment: Is it a MUST to raise an exception? What if you try to use OnSubjobOk when coming out of tJava_11?

Comment: @BalazsGunics Sorry, did not understand what you said. Currently, I am manually raising an exception in tJava_11. However, the same component could also have raised some kind of runtime exception by its own. Whichever way, how do we handle the errors/exception and can still continue with the main flow without using subjobs?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the runif and handle both scenarios in the get_QAR_ID into context component. ie query the database component's NB_LINE after variable, if it's <1 raise the error, else set the value. Your job would then flow to the onSubjobOk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :
[image]

In `tJava_1` you do your error logging if no row is returned by your query, and you continue to the next subjob. No need to throw an exception here only to catch it immediately after.

If any row is found, you continue to the next subjob (`tJava_2`) with an If trigger.

Comment: Although, here I am manually raising the exception, it is quite possible that talend can also raise exception at run-time. I got your point about suppressing the exception itself, but can we handle it if it is raised and still can continue with the OnSubJobOk flow? (without using subjobs)